# функция выводит лишние данные

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Есть у меня функция, в которой должно быть два действия: перезапись сессии ( `$_SESSION['admins'] = var_dump($data)` ) и запись + выведение переменной $table (при вызове функции с помощью AJAX содержимое этой самой таблицы должно заменяться). Сам код такой:

```php
$_SESSION['admins'] = var_dump($data);
$table = 'бла-бла-бла';
exit($table);
```

Результат передаётся в AJAX-функцию:

```
function load_from_db( url, name ) {

    $.ajax({

        url: '/' + url,
        type: 'POST',
        data: name + '_f=1',
        cache: false,
        success: function( result ) {

            $("#table_with_result").html( result );

        }

    })

}
```

И вот в "result" как раз таки попадает $_SESSION['admins'], которого там быть не должно. Как от него избавиться?

Comment: Вы в курсе что делает `var_dump`?

Comment: цитата из пхп.нет: var_dump — Выводит информацию о переменной

Comment: Ну и вы понимаете что это значит?

Answer (score 0):

думаю надо так

```
$_SESSION['admins'] = $data;
```

var_dump - выводит информацию о переменной в текстовом виде. Часто это используют при отладке. Здесь она лишняя.